# Paste DataGridView cells to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I’m trying to find a quicker way to paste the values of the DataGridView cells to an Excel spreadsheet. The code below works but it’s really slow as it loops through each cell. Hoping someone please help with speeding this up.

Thanks in advance.

```
          For i = 0 To PartsDataGridView.RowCount - 1
                If PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "Positive" Then

                    lr3 = WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1

                    With WS
                        .Range("A" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                        .Range("B" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                        .Range("C" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                        .Range("D" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                        .Range("E" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
                        .Range("F" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
                        .Range("G" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
                        .Range("H" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value
                        .Range("I" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value
                        .Range("J" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value
                        .Range("K" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value
                        .Range("L" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value
                    End With

                End If
          Next
```

Comment: You're trying to speed it up? Are you using interop? If so, don't use interop use a NuGet package such as `DocumentFormat.Openxml` or `ClosedXML`.  However, if using interop, given `excelApp = new Excel.Application();` . You could disable user control `excelApp.UserControl = false;`, and then disable screen updating `excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;` . Update your data, then re-enable screen updating and user control.

Comment: By speeding it up I mean copying the data row by row rather than cell by cell. I imagine this would speed up the process massively. Apologies for not being clear about this before. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is it an actual requirement to use Excel?  Could you output it to a csv or other delimited text for example?  Otherwise, using one of the many 3rd party tools such as what has already been suggested

Comment: What do you consider slow? How much data (rows, columns)? Is it necessary to have Excel open during this operation? Or are you opening the file with Excel after it's been created? What's the file extension of the Excel file (ex: .xlsx)?

Comment: Excel is required and necessary to to be open during execution. There could be up to 100 rows of data in the DataGridView so pasting cell by cell is very slow. Is there a way to paste the entire row into excel at once?

Comment: How did you fill the grid? Is there a `DataTable` being used as a `DataSource`?

Comment: Hi @Mary. There is no Datasource. The grid was filled in much the same way (cell by cell). I was hoping something like the following would work.`WS.Range("A" & lr3 & ":L" & lr3).Value = PartsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1 - 12).Value` I Understand that `Cells(1 - 12)` is not correct but I don't know how else to write it here.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you can paste arrays into Excel Interop Ranges.

I used something like this:

In this case array is two dimensional array of your data

```
Worksheet.Range("A2:T" + array.GetLength(0).ToString).Value2 = array
```

This increased my speed but I was working with thousands of Rows, I am not sure by how much this will increase your code